# xcode 申請

Tags: xcode

xcode で申請を行うとこうなるのはなぜでしょう ？ [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 何の申請か示されていませんのでそこは無視しますが、"We'll be back soon（すぐ戻ります）"なら、単にAppleのサイトの調子が悪くてアクセスできないのでしょう。リンクで示されたステータスページを見ながら待つとよいと思います。コメントが投稿されるころにはもう復帰していると思いますが…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/maintenance/

にアクセスすると
We'll be back soon.
になりますね。

しばらく様子をみてはいかがでしょう。